# Web2py - Insert Record in Second Tabel on Registration

Tags: web2py

I'm building a Web2py application that uses MongoDB as its primary database. To simplify authentication, I'm sticking with SQLite (eventually MySQL) for member management.

When a user registers, a record is created in the SQL database. Upon registration, I'd like the same record to be inserted in MongoDB. I can easily write the query to insert the record in Mongo, but I can't find the controller that manages this process (so that I can access the vars and insert them in Mongo).

Any guidance that you could provide would be great. If there a way to identify when the auth record changes (so that I can update the Mongo record), that would be nice too but a secondary requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgive my unfamiliarity with web2py but it seems to be odd that you store data in MongoDB but store users in MySQL, if I understand correctly just because web2py uses a SQL database for user management. I guess it is some default config in web2py. I thinks you should try to have web2py store the users in the MongoDB in the first place, and not store users both in MySQL and MongoDB.

Comment: As I understand it, Web2py's authentication system doesn't work with MongoDB, and I haven't been able to build a custom workaround for it. So, to simplify, I'm trying to keep member management in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started with the scaffolding app, in the `default.py` controller, you probably have a function like:

```
def user():
    return dict(form=auth())
```

Calling the `auth` object handles processing for all Auth actions (the particular action is determined based on the first URL arg after /default/user -- so, /default/user/register triggers the registration action). The problem with interjecting code here is that Auth is typically configured to redirect after registration, so the code will not be executed.

One solution is to set up Auth callback functions. `auth.settings.register_onaccept` and `auth.settings.profile_onaccept` are lists of callbacks that are called after a successful registration or profile update. The associated Auth `form` object is passed to these callbacks, and the inserted/updated values can be found in `form.vars` (`form.vars.id` is the user ID). See [this section of the docs](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Auth-Settings-and-messages) for a registration example.

Another option is to set up [`_after_insert` and `_after_update` callbacks](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#before-and-after-callbacks) on the `db.auth_user` table. Assuming the MongoDB DAL object is called `mongo` and the `db.auth_user.id` is stored in a field called `user_id`:

```
def copy_user(fields, id):
    fields.update(user_id=id)
    mongo.auth_user.insert(**fields)

def update_user(dal_set, fields):
    id = dal_set.select(db.auth_user.id)[0].id
    mongo(mongo.auth_user.user_id == id).update(**fields)

db.auth_user._after_insert.append(copy_user)
db.auth_user._after_update.append(update_user)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works even if the records are updated outside of the Auth system (e.g., via the appadmin functionality).

Comment: Let's say I try the second option you propose. In db.py, I set "auth.settings.register_onaccept = URL('copy_user')". Then, in default.py I set "def copy_user(): mongo.collection.auth_user.insert({'id':form.vars.id})". This is using pymongo and not the DAL. When I do this, I get an error that string object is not callable. Am I applying the callback solution incorrectly?

Comment: Okay, just needed to move auth.settings.register_onaccept to default.py and change URL('copy_user') to simply copy_user. Thank you!